# create file containing '/' in file name in python

Tags: python-2.7, file-handling

how can I create a file in python if the filename contains '/'

```
url='https://www.udacity.com/cs101x/index.html'
f=open(url,'w')
f.write('123')
f.close()
```

above code produces an error as

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "9.py", line 2, in <module>
f=open(url,'w')
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('w') or filename:https://www.udacity.com/cs101x/index.html'
```

Comment: You can't create a filename with the path separator in the name. Your OS won't allow it. The `/` is reserved to separate elements of the file path (directories).

Comment: you could create a file like this _if the path existed_ (not with http prefix for sure!) in that case you would just create a file called `index.html`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use os.path.basename() to isolate the filename.

```
import os
url='https://www.udacity.com/cs101x/index.html'
filename = os.path.basename(url)
f=open(filename,'w')
f.write('123')
f.close()
```

This will create a file called index.html